# Paypal MPL iOS error -1

Tags: ios, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

My PayPal MPL integration which has been working correctly,but problem come from when initialize paypal library .

```
[PayPal initializeWithAppID:@"APP-80W284485P519543T" forEnvironment:ENV_SANDBOX];
```

It gives the following error:

```
Checking Error********************
Posting Error: -1
Internal server error.
```

Has anyone else experienced this?

I'm running Xcode 6.0.1 and this occurs in both iOS 7 & 8

Comment: Having the same issue. Did you find solution?

Comment: Issue solved. Where are you initializing the paypal?

Comment: We have initialised it in the app delegate class in didFinishLaunching method.

Comment: Remove from there. Do it in the `ViewDidLoad` of your ViewController.

Answer (score 6):

I was also stuck at the same error and finally found the solution by adding 
 "bundle display name" in info.plist.                                        Without it I was  getting posting error.

Comment: Perfect It, saved my another day. By as soon it opens, It calls "paymentLibraryExit" and it dismissed, any suggestion?